# How can I deploy ruby on rails application to mochahost using capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails deployment.  I have created my first simple ruby on rails application, but I am struggling to properly get it onto my server.

In my research, I learned about the various ways to deploy a ror app to my own server, and it seems that using capistrano would be the way to do it.  However, it is not clear to me how to use capistrano to launch my app.

What are the steps that I need to take in order to launch my app?  Do I need to use git, I prefer not to..  I don't want to use Heroku.

It just seems that deploying the application should be really easy and I am struggling with it.  If I am using the non-optimal tools let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capistrano is primarily used to deploy apps, not to launch them. Capistrano is of course capable of launching Rails apps, but how to do that depends on how your app is set up.

You should do some research on using nginx (HTTP server) and Unicorn (Rack server) together with Capistrano. It might take some time setting everything up, but once in working condition, they’ll make deploying your app close to enjoyable.

Regarding actually deploying your app: Heroku is not required in order to use Git, but if you really don’t want to use any kind of versions system (though I highly recommend that you do), this blog post might help you on your way: http://www.maxkpage.com/blog/capistrano-rails-deploy-without-svn-or-git/